# PROOF of $e^x > x^m$, $\forall x>1$

Tags: limits, inequality

Directly using the definition of exp(x) as an infinite series, prove exp(x) ≥ x^m for all
x ≥ 1 and m ∈ N.

I have tried truncating the infinite series and showing that the cut off sum is still greater than x^m, which should prove this, but I have always ended up proving some multiple of exp(x) is greater, instead of exp(x) itself.

Note: I am strictly bound to using the summation of x^n/n! definition of exp(x) as a power series and not the (1+x/n)^n definition.

Comment: What if $x=2$ and $m=3$?

Comment: That explains a lot as to why I was only able to prove certain multiples of e^x being greater than x^m. I guess the question my instructor gave me isn't correct.

Comment: What you can show is that $e^x\gt x^m$ for all *sufficiently large* values of $x$.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. The question told us to use this result to prove x^m/e^x goes to zero as x tends to infinity. Clearly, this result is not true for all x>1 and all m in natural numbers.

Comment: But what would be a way to prove limit of e^x/x^m as x goes to infinity is zero? I cannot use L'hopital's rule or simply state that e^x increases faster than x^m does so the limit is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e^x\geq x^m$, then $x\geq mln(x)$, or $m\leq \cfrac{x}{ln(x)}$, and since $\cfrac{x}{ln(x)}$ is not bounded and does not have any horizontal asymptotes, there will eventually be some $x$ such that this inequality is satisfied

Answer (score 0):

With series, assuming $x>1,\ $ we have

$e^x-x^m=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots +(\frac{1}{m!}-1)x^m+\frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}+\cdots\ge$

$ 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots -x^m+\frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}+\cdots\ge $

$-x^m+\frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$ and this expression is greater than zero if $x$ is large enough.

edit: as Calum points out, the proof is a one liner:

$e^x > \frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}\Rightarrow e^x -x^m>\frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}-x^m>0$ if $x$ is large enough.

Comment: Or even just write $e^x > \frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$.

Comment: No, because you have the negative term $(\frac{1}{m!}-1)x^m$ to deal with

Comment: Yep. I guess I went around the block on this one. Ugh. This will do: $e^x > \frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}\Rightarrow e^x -x^m>\frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}-x^m>0$ if $x$ is large enough. If you post it a s an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: Sounds good. btw: I feel the same way about comments. Especially longer threads of them,  the ones that lead to dead ends, or become incomprehensible.